# argmax on 2 axis for 3-d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to obtain a 1D array of indexes from a 3D matrix.

For instance given `x = np.random.randint(10, size=(10,3,3))`, I'd like to do something like `np.argmax(x, axis=(1,2))` just like you can do with `np.max`, that is, obtain a 1D array of length 10 containing the indexes (0 to 8) of the maximums of each submatrix of size `(3,3)`.

I have not found anything helpful so far and I want to avoid looping on the first dimension (and use `np.argmax(x)`) as it is quite big.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape to merge those last two axes and then use `np.argmax` -

```
idx = x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1).argmax(-1)
out = np.unravel_index(idx, x.shape[-2:])
```

Sample run -

```
In [263]: x = np.random.randint(10, size=(4,3,3))

In [264]: x
Out[264]: 
array([[[0, 9, 2],
        [7, 7, 8],
        [2, 5, 9]],

       [[1, 7, 2],
        [8, 9, 0],
        [2, 8, 3]],

       [[7, 5, 0],
        [7, 1, 6],
        [5, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 7, 3],
        [5, 4, 1],
        [9, 8, 9]]])

In [265]: idx = x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1).argmax(-1)

In [266]: np.unravel_index(idx, x.shape[-2:])
Out[266]: (array([0, 1, 0, 2]), array([1, 1, 0, 0]))
```

If you meant getting the merged index, then its simpler -

```
x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1).argmax(1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [283]: x
Out[283]: 
array([[[2, 3, 7],
        [8, 1, 0],
        [3, 6, 9]],

       [[8, 0, 5],
        [2, 2, 9],
        [9, 0, 9]],

       [[1, 9, 2],
        [5, 0, 3],
        [7, 2, 1]],

       [[1, 6, 5],
        [2, 3, 7],
        [7, 4, 6]]])

In [284]: x.reshape(x.shape[0],-1).argmax(1)
Out[284]: array([8, 5, 1, 5])
```

Comment: I did mean the merged index. Thanks for your help!